# valid order for attributes of input type tag

Tags: html

I know it's very basic question and hope not so important, but i want to know the  answer, please don't suggest only refer links.

we all daily face `<input>` type tag  and their attributes (`type, class, id, value, name, size, maxlength, tabindex etc..`), I just want to know

- is there any specific order required for attributes in `<input>` tag or can we use any order?
- if there an order then what is it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use any sequence

Answer (score 68):

Already been answered, but my full and expanded answer is:

- There is no predefined order for the attributes in terms of passing w3c validation... it's completely up to you.

However, you should introduce your own standard and stick to it.

If there are multiple coders working on the application they should all stick to the same standard.

If you are a team leader, web-dev business owner, manager, etc, it is your responsibility to encourage (and enforce) a culture that uses this standard.

When doing code reviews the attribute order should be checked, and anything that fails you should make the coder responsible fix it up... they'll only muck it up once or twice if they know they'll have to rewrite their code!!!

And why all this fuss and bother over attribute order?

- This will increase code development and debugging speed.
- It makes code more readable
- It encourages the coders (or you) to pay attention to the little details
- It helps to fosters an environment of "accountability for your own code"

My personal preference is:

1. type (so you can instantly see what it is)
2. id
3. class (I like to keep 2 and 3 together as they are the most common js/jQuery selectors)
4. name
5. value (I like to keep 4 and 5 next to each other so you can quickly reference what input it is and it's value).
6. All others (like checked, max-size, etc)
7. style
8. tabindex (I like 7 and 8 to be at the end as it's "non-relevant", in terms of the actual functionality, they are more styling/usability stuff, keep 'em out of the way!

Comment: I also like `<label for="..." id class etc>`. It sounds like English :)

Comment: Suppose I wanted to write a custom "HTML lint" rule that would try to enforce  agreed upon conventions, for example that id and class are always next to one another, etc. Where would I start? There must be tools that I could leverage, I just cannot think of them. For my html files, they will be either verbatim or templated and I would be able to generate a predictable version once by running some sort of pre-processor (as opposed to completely dynamic generation of the content depending on what the user requested). So, I want to run html lint as git post-receive hook. Any suggestions/tools?

Comment: I like this approach

Answer (score 9):

Here's code guide from [Mark Otto](https://twitter.com/mdo)

[General attribute order guide](http://codeguide.co/#html-attribute-order)

He gives a general guideline to HTML CSS and JS although nothing specific about input tags alone. I think it's a good read.

Answer (score 7):

The order of attributes in HTML elements doesn't matter at all. You can write the attributes in any order you like.

Comment: but what sequence should be prefer, in practical?
i hope first of all `typ`e should b defined, then `class` and then `id`,`value`  etc...

Comment: It's up to you - just be consistent.

Comment: It might matter a bit for a very small performance impact on the reconciliation of DOM (React Viber).

Answer (score 5):

my preference is: id, name, type, class, attributes (like selected, checked), value