# Link back to original link source (both links on the same page) and vice-versa

Tags: html, css

## 2 "vice-versa"-links on the same webpage

What is the easiest way to ...

- ... have LINK1 referring to LINK2

and

- ... have LINK2 referring back to LINK1?

---

The most basic way of doing this would be perhaps via a `span` with a unique `id`:

`<a href=#LINK2><span id="LINK1>This is LINK1 referring to LINK2</span><a/>`

`<a href=#LINK1><span id="LINK2>This is LINK2, which refers back to LINK1.</span></a>`

However, is there perhaps a faster, less labor-intensive and more elegant solution (cf. documents under construction, dynamic or large files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use

```
<a href="#link2" id="link1">This is LINK1 referring to LINK2.<a/>
<a href="#link1" id="link2">This is LINK2, which refers back to LINK1.</a>
```

```css
.space {
  height: 100000px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#link2" id="link1">This is LINK1 referring to LINK2.<a/>
<span class="space"></span>
<a href="#link1" id="link2">This is LINK2, which refers back to LINK1.</a>
```

Comment: That's true, I have should have thought of that! That facilitates the job, thanks. --- Is there perhaps a convention on the order of `href`'s and `id`'s in `a`'s? Perhaps for the visual impaired. You never know ... =)

Comment: @VincentVerheyen The order of attributes doesn't matter. See [valid order for attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2720618/1529630).