# AngularJS: preferable order of class="" and ng-click="" within a tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, function, angularjs-directive

Are there any preferences between

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="superalert()" title="">Show alert</button>

<button ng-click="superalert()" class="btn" title="">Show alert</button>
```

I don't see any difference, but probably there are some preferences or tricky pitfalls.

Comment: Not sure why someone down voted this question without a comment.

Comment: That's an April Fool's jokes I guess

Comment: @Leonprou. Nope. It's too early for jokes. I'm not from Japan or Russia or Australia.

Comment: @leonprou, The question is in regards to convention - always good to consider especially with every JS framework bringing in their own declarative attributed in standard HTML.

Comment: @Haradzieniec - valid question regarding convention in the world where every JS framework from Dojo to Angular want their own declarative attributes polluting vanilla HTML.

Comment: See [valid order for attributes of input type tag](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2720618/1529630)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such HTML does not dictate the order of attributes. But I would recommend for your own benefit to stick to one standard. I see similar discussions on this subject that you may find value on similar lines - [valid order for attributes of input type tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720618/valid-order-for-attributes-of-input-type-tag). There is one response in that discussion that points to a page on [conventions](http://codeguide.co/#html-attribute-order) containing attribute order. These conventions are from [Mark Otto](https://twitter.com/mdo). I see there are no details on AngularJS attributes specifically in these so I would modify these conventions to suite the needs of the tech stack used (Angular in your case).

Answer (score 1):

There is no required order -- you can do whatever sequence you prefer.

I typically give preference to`id`, `class`, `name`, etc. (standard HTML attributes), followed by the `ng-___` attributes. I alphabetize the Angular attributes just to simplify finding a specific attribute if an element has many.