# In What order should you declare “id” and “class” for the same HTML element, and why?

Tags: html, css, class

**In What order should you declare “id” and “class” for the same HTML element, and why ?** *It seems that my questions is reported for being a duplicate, but mine is referring to a specific H1 HTML element in this case. Thank you*

```
<h1 id="orange-text" class="pink-text blue-text">Hello World!</h1>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, any order is fine

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css

Comment: `id` is uniqe to this element and `class` can be se to multiple elements but you desside what to define and the order does not matter

Comment: He's not asking what the difference between an id and a class is, he's asking about the *order*

Comment: Just depends on individual coding style~ :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [valid order for attributes of input type tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720618/valid-order-for-attributes-of-input-type-tag)

Comment: HTML isn't attribute sensitive

Comment: It seems that my questions is reported for being a duplicate, but mine is referring to a specific H1 HTML element in this case. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no predefined order for the attributes in terms of passing w3c validation... it's completely up to you. Any order of HTML attributes will have no effect on performance either.

Answer (score 1):

Order is not important, both of them works correctly. But I always add "id" before "class" because I think is easier to read and the "id" provide more information.

Comment: "id" is only one-word identifier, but class may have a lot of words, which potentially can provide more information. First of all be consistent in your notation/code style, no matter what style do you prefer -- it's not important in current case

Comment: It's my own rule. I should use "id" for javascript actions, por example. But everyone will have their own style.